# How to get the width and height of a Win2D CanvasBitmap during CreateResources?

Tags: windows-runtime, win2d

I have some simple XAML using [Win2D](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm):

```
<canvas:CanvasControl 
    Width="270"
    Height="480"
    x:Name="MainCanvas"
    ClearColor="CornflowerBlue"
    Draw="MainCanvas_Draw" 
    CreateResources="MainCanvas_CreateResources"/>
```

In the `MainCanvas_CreateResources(CanvasControl, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs)` method I would like to test the bounds of a [CanvasBitmap](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap.htm) and, if necessary, rotate it. To do this I need to call,[CanvasBitmap.GetBounds](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_GetBounds.htm). But that takes a [CanvasDrawingSession](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession.htm). Once I am in CanvasControl's Draw event I'm OK because CanvasDrawEventArgs has a DrawingSession property. But while I am setting up resources how do I find out the bounds of a CanvasBitmap, or if that's not possible what stucture would I use to find the bounds of the underlying bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CanvasBitmap.Size](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/P_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_Size.htm) or [CanvasBitmap.Bounds](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/P_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_Bounds.htm) properties.